# Integrating stripe with android app

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am trying to support stripe payments from my android application but it won't run.  Is the java incompatible? My code and errors are below:

```
package io.noq.kiosk.android;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.exception.APIConnectionException;
import com.stripe.exception.AuthenticationException;

import com.stripe.exception.CardException;
import com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException;
import com.stripe.exception.StripeException;
import com.stripe.model.Charge;

import io.noq.android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class OnSwipeActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Stripe.apiKey = "the secret (intentionally omitting)";
        Map<String, Object> chargeMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        chargeMap.put("amount", 100);
        chargeMap.put("currency", "usd");

        Map<String, Object> cardMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        cardMap.put("number", "4242424242424242");
        cardMap.put("exp_month", 12);
        cardMap.put("exp_year", 2013);
        chargeMap.put("card", cardMap);

        try {
            Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeMap);
            System.out.println(charge);
            Log.i("Status is: " + "exiting try onCreate-PayActivity", "let's see what goes out....");
            System.out.println("Status is: "+ "exiting try onCreate-PayActivity");
        } catch (CardException e) {
            // Since it's a decline, CardException will be caught
            System.out.println("CardException is: " + e.getCode());
            System.out.println("CardException is: " + e.getParam());
            Log.i(OnSwipeActivity.class.getName(), "e.getCode() ...." + e.getCode());
        } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
            // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            System.out.println("InvalidRequestException: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.i(OnSwipeActivity.class.getName(),"e.getCode() ...." + e.getCause());
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            // Authentication with Stripe's API failed (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            System.out.println("AuthenticationException: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.i(OnSwipeActivity.class.getName(), "e.getCode() ...." + e.getCause());
        } catch (APIConnectionException e) {
            // Network communication with Stripe failed
            System.out.println("APIConnectionException: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.i(OnSwipeActivity.class.getName(), "e.getCode() ...." + e.getCause());
        } catch (StripeException e) {
            // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send yourself an email
            System.out.println("StripeException: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.i(OnSwipeActivity.class.getName(), "e.getCode() ...." + e.getCause());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.i(OnSwipeActivity.class.getName(), "e.getCode() ...." + e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors:

> 12-25 05:34:22.625: W/dalvikvm(801): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40a70930)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError                           com.stripe.Stripe
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at io.noq.kiosk.android.OnSwipeActivity.onCreate(OnSwipeActivity.java:26)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 12-25 05:34:22.647: E/AndroidRuntime(801):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I can't confirm that the java library is compatible, but there is an application witch use strip https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.dina.striped

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Strip java library on an android project. I have implemented a Poc using the Test class from [StripTest](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/stripe/StripeTest.java)

You have to import the libraries as the picture: [image: Imported libraries]

You can test with a sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG                 = "TestStrip";
    static Map<String, Object> defaultCardParams   = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    static Map<String, Object> defaultChargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Stripe.apiKey = "tGN0bIwXnHdwOa85VABjPdSn8nWY7G7I";
        init();
        Map<String, Object> chargeMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chargeMap.put("amount", 100);
        chargeMap.put("currency", "usd");
        Map<String, Object> cardMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        cardMap.put("number", "4242424242424242");
        cardMap.put("exp_month", 12);
        cardMap.put("exp_year", 2013);
        chargeMap.put("card", cardMap);

        try {
            Charge createdCharge = Charge.create(defaultChargeParams);
            Fee fee = createdCharge.getFeeDetails().get(0);
            Preconditions.checkState("stripe_fee".equals(fee.getType()), "Stripe fee error.");
            Preconditions.checkState(createdCharge.getFee() == fee.getAmount(), "Error ");
        } catch (StripeException e) {
            // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send yourself an email
            Log.e(TAG, "e.getCode() ...." + e.getCause());
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        defaultCardParams.put("number", "4242424242424242");
        defaultCardParams.put("exp_month", 12);
        defaultCardParams.put("exp_year", 2015);
        defaultCardParams.put("cvc", "123");
        defaultCardParams.put("name", "Java Bindings Cardholder");
        defaultCardParams.put("address_line1", "140 2nd Street");
        defaultCardParams.put("address_line2", "4th Floor");
        defaultCardParams.put("address_city", "San Francisco");
        defaultCardParams.put("address_zip", "94105");
        defaultCardParams.put("address_state", "CA");
        defaultCardParams.put("address_country", "USA");
        defaultChargeParams.put("amount", 100);
        defaultChargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
        defaultChargeParams.put("card", defaultCardParams);
    }
}
```

Do no forget to add  to the android manifest.
mail me if you needs the sample project sources.

Comment: Hi Anis,                                                                          I am developing an android app through user will pay using credit card and i will receive the money. how can i use the stripe. please help me.

Comment: @Anis: Please provide me the source code for payment through stripe sdk.

Comment: must have a stripe account first after that refer to stripe tutorial. If you are looking just for payment over credit card, many other solutions exists. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564482/how-to-implement-credit-card-payment-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

```
In Android Studio
add in gradle 
 compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
==============================================

 Card card = new Card(cardnumber,exp.month,exp.year,cvv);
boolean validation = card.validateCard();
        if (validation) {
            startProgress();
            new Stripe().createToken(
                    card,
                    PUBLISHABLE_STRIPE_KEY,
                    new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            // you can get transcation token
                        }
                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            handleError(error.getLocalizedMessage());
                            finishProgress();
                        }
                    });
        } else if (!card.validateNumber()) {
            handleError("The card number that you entered is invalid");
        } else if (!card.validateExpiryDate()) {
            handleError("The expiration date that you entered is invalid");
        } else if (!card.validateCVC()) {
            handleError("The CVC code that you entered is invalid");
        } else {
            handleError("The card details that you entered are invalid");
        }
```